# Get focus on current target

Tags: javascript

I have an input field where the input number should not be less than 2 and if he proceeded to the next field the validation should be done and the focus must return to the first input field.                 I tried event.target.focus(); FormFields=document.getElementsByTagName("input"); For(i=0;i

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please show some code.

Comment: FormFields=document.getElementsByTagName("input");                 For(i=0;i<FormFields.length;i++) { FormFields[i].onchange=check;}                                                                  Function check(event){currentvalue=event.currentTarget.value;if(currentvalue<2){event.currentTarget.focus();}}

Comment: In your question, not a comment.

Comment: Mentioned in question too

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use onBlur event. Look at this example:

```
const t = document.querySelector('#t');
const handler = (event) => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    const p = parseInt(value);
    if (isNaN(p) || p < 2) {
      return event.target.focus();
    }
};
t.addEventListener('blur', handler);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9a2tLgy4/

Comment: FormFields=document.getElementsByTagName("input");                 For(i=0;i<FormFields.length;i++) { FormFields[i].onchange=check;}                                                                  Function check(event){currentvalue=event.currentTarget.value;if(currentvalue<2){event.currentTarget.focus();}}.       This is what I'm trying using pure js